# How can I write to a file from a React component?

Tags: node.js, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I have a SideNav menu that looks for a file called route.js that has a array inside it called routes. I am trying to change the value of routes in routes.js from another component. I want to be able to add an delete the physical array in the file routes.js from a component. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import Shop from "examples/Icons/Shop";
// import Office from "examples/Icons/Office";

const routes = [
  {
    type: "collapse",
    name: "Our Mission",
    key: "dashboards",
    icon: <Shop size="12px" />,
    collapse: [
      {
        name: "Ways We can Help",
        key: "default",
        route: "/dashboards/default",
        component: Default,
      },
      {
        name: "How It Works",
        key: "automotive",
        route: "/dashboards/automotive",
        component: Automotive,
      },
      {
        name: "Who We Are",
        key: "smart-home",
        route: "/dashboards/smart-home",
        component: SmartHome,
      },
    ],
  },
  { type: "title", title: " ", key: "space1" },
  {
    type: "collapse",
    name: "Services",
    key: "services",
    icon: <Shop size="12px" />,
    href: "https://github.com/creativetimofficial/ct-soft-ui-dashboard-pro-material-ui/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md",
    component: Default,
    noCollapse: true,
  },
];
export default routes;
```

Component accessing the routes.js

```
import routes from "../../../routes";
const loggedroutes = [
  {
    type: "collapse",
    name: "Profile",
    key: "profile",
    icon: <CgProfile size="12px" color="blue" />,
    route: "/dashboards/Default",
    collapse: [],
  },
  {
    type: "collapse",
    name: "Calendar",
    key: "calendar",
    component: link,
    route: "/dashboards/Default",
    icon: <GoCalendar size="12px" color="blue" />,
    collapse: [],
  },
]

routes = loggedinroutes;
```

i want to change the data in routes.js to match the array loggedinroutes

Comment: What is a "physical array"?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to write to a file? That's different than updating an array, which is in memory.

Comment: i want to write to the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok without knowing too much of what you're doing, I put together a quick sandbox on how I would go about this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-shirley-q9mhz?file=/src/routes.js

I would basically use logic based on either a button click/state/page query/etc and pass that through a function that would load the routes in your navbar dynamically. in the app.js file you can see how I used the useState() hook with button clicks to dynamically load the routes.

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to accomplish this but I hope this gets you in the right direction!

Comment: meaning i want to save an array located in the routes.js file . not just the state but the actual file.

Comment: Derek, please see [answer]. Links to solutions aren't adequate on SO.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I have routes.js which stores an json array used to populate a menu. I want to load the array from routes.js in my components and be able to save the array back to routes.js. I am not trying to load and save  the array state. i want to actually write to the file from jsx saving the array back to the routes.js file.

Comment: Maybe someone could weigh in but I don't believe you can physically write to the jsx file after compile. You would need to either do what I showed in the code example, or you could write the data to a database/local storage/cookie or some other type of cache I'm not thinking of, then call it from your code, but I'm not clear on why you'd need to do that for a menu?